# Imprimir o nome do usuário na página

Tags: php, html

Tenho um página de login que quando o usuário loga é redirecionado para uma página chamada `Minhaconta.php` que contém o seguinte código:

```
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><?php echo $_SESSION['nome']; ?><span class="caret"></span></a>                      
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">                          
                        <li><a href="MinhacontaPt-BR.php">&#128102; Perfil</a></li>                         
                        <li><a href="../Conexao/sair.php" class="fa fa-sign-out"> Sair</a></li>                         
                    </ul>
```

Consigo pegar o nome dele e imprimir nessa página, só que, quando vou para a página inicial do meu site, o nome dele não imprime.

Como posso fazer isso?

Quando o usuário tiver logado, na parte inicial, aparece "minha conta e sair" ao invés de "login e registrar". E, em cima, onde está minha conta, aparece o nome do usuário.

```
                     <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">&#128102; Minha conta<span class="caret"></span></a>                     
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">                          
                    <li><a href="CadastrarPT-BR.php">Registrar-se</a></li>
                    <li><a href="loginPT-BR.php">Entrar</a></li>                        
                    </ul>   
                    </li>
```

Eu abri a sessão somente na página de `Minhaconta.php`.

Comment: Kd o código da sua página inicial?!

Comment: <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">&#128102; Minha conta<span class="caret"></span></a>      
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">       
      <li><a href="CadastrarPT-BR.php">Registrar-se</a></li>
      <li><a href="loginPT-BR.php">Entrar</a></li>      
      </ul> 
      </li>

Comment: @PedroLukas Clique em **[edit]** e poste seu código.

Comment: Tem mais códigos, só mandei essa parte pq é aqui que eu quero quando o usuário esteja logado apareça o nome dele e em vez de registar e logar, apareça minha conta e sair.

Comment: Pedro, pense que para te ajudar, precisamos do mínimo possível para reproduzir seu problema. Você até explicou bem, mas não temos como adivinhar como está o seu código como um todo. Você pode [edit] a sua pergunta e adicionar o código referente a ela.

Comment: Desculpas, já mandei o código aí, ver se vc consegue entender melhor.

Comment: Ainda tem pouco código. Só vai gerar mais perguntas. Quer ver?! Lembrou de iniciar a sessão na sua página inicial: `session_start()`?!

Comment: Quer dizer, cara é muito código mano, não sei como enviar por aqui e vai embolar vocês mais ainda, sim, eu abri a sessão somente na página de Minhaconta.php

Comment: Pq é uma loja nessa parte inicial, aonde tem carrousel, vitrines, etc. aí se eu mandar acho que vai embolar vocês e toda vez que tento mandar buga k

Answer (score -1):

> Eu abri a sessão somente na página de Minhaconta.php

Conforme a documentação do PHP, a sessão deve ser iniciada ou resumida sempre que for acessar as informações guardadas nela:

> *session_start() cria uma sessão ou resume a sessão atual baseado em um id de sessão passado via GET ou POST, ou passado via cookie.* - [PHP: session_start](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-start.php)

Sendo assim, inicie/resuma a sessão, também, na sua página inicial.

É normal iniciar a sessão direto na raiz do seu projeto quando se tem um arquivo de configurações comum a todas as suas páginas/scripts. Mas isso pode ser diferente para cada projeto...

Outra questão: a sessão deve ser iniciada antes de quaisquer saídas de código. O exemplo a seguir vai gerar um erro:

```
<?php
echo 'Hello world!';
session_start();
```

O correto é:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo 'Hello world';
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode adicionar uma condição na página inicial que verifica se existe um usuário logado:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['nome'])) { ?>

    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <?php echo $_SESSION['nome']; ?><span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="MinhacontaPt-BR.php">&#128102; Perfil</a></li>
        <li><a href="../Conexao/sair.php" class="fa fa-sign-out"> Sair</a></li>
      </ul>

<?php } else { ?>

    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">&#128102; Minha conta<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="CadastrarPT-BR.php">Registrar-se</a></li>
        <li><a href="loginPT-BR.php">Entrar</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

<?php } ?>
```

Não esqueça de iniciar as sessões (`session_start();`) nas páginas necessárias

Comment: VLwww cara me ajudou!! <3